# Fail to solve set of PDEs

Tags: differential-equations

I tried to solve `a[t,z]` and `u[t,z]` from set of PDES.
Here `a[t,z]` describes laser incident on material where electrons osciallate at velocity `u[t,z]`. At boundary `z=0`, laser intensity is `a[t,0]`; at initial time `t=0`, electrons osciallate uniformally at velocity of `u[0,z]`.

```
n=100;B=10;p=10^(-5);a0=0.01;u0=0.001
pdes={D[u[t,z],t]==-a[t,z]-p*n*T^(-3/2)*u[t,z]+I*u[t,z]*B, D[a[t,z],z]==-Im[k]*a[t,z]}/.k->(1-n/(1-B+I*p*n*T^(-3/2)))/.T->0.5*u[t,z]^2;
bc={a[t,0]==a0};
ic={u[0,z]==u0};
s=NDSolve[{pdes,bc,ic},{a,u},{t,0,1},{z,0,1}]
ContourPlot[Evaluate[Re[u[t, z]] /.s], {t, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

The I got error message "NDSolve::femcnsd: The PDE coefficient -a[t,z]+10 I u[t,z]-(0.0149907 u[t,z])/(u[t,z]^(3/2))^(3/2)-(u^(1,0))[t,z] does not evaluate to a numeric scalar at the coordinate {1.,1.}; it evaluated to Indeterminate instead."

When I use `T^(3/2)` instead of `T^(-3/2)` and  `k` instead of `Im[k]`. It works.

As suggested by user21, I used method in NDSolve

```
s = NDSolve[{pdes, bc, ic}, {a, u}, {t, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 2}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines"}]
```

Then I got error message which I do not understand: NDSolve::ivone: Boundary values may only be specified for one independent variable. Initial values may only be specified at one value of the other independent variable.

I still do not understand?

Comment: Incorrect syntax. Use: `T^(-3/2)` not `T^{-3/2}`

Comment: Thank you. I corrected it. Same problems exist.

Comment: Use the `NDSolve` method option `Method -> {"MethodOfLines"}`. That will give you a different set of messages and you need to address those issues; for example give an initial condition for `a`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried and made progress. But still not solved, And I do not undertand the error message.

Comment: What is the initial condition for `a`?

Comment: Initial condiition of a is a[0,z]=a0*UnitStep[-z]. Is it required?

Comment: @xzczd, in my 2nd PDE, `k` is dependent on `T=0.5*u[t,z]^2`. Thus, it is coupled to 1st PDE. In this way, I did not solve it first.

Comment: Sorry, I somewhat overlooked it. The answer shown in your latest question should be applicable to the problem, as long as the problem itself is correct.