# Need more equations in PDEs by NDSolve? Bug of mma?

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve set of pdes as below

```
ClearAll["Global`*"] ;
n = 100;
pde = {D[S[t, z, r], z] == -S[t, z, r], 
D[T[t, z, r], t] == n^-1 S[t, z, r]};
ic = {T[0, z, r] == 1, S[t, 0, r] == Exp[-r^2]};
sol = NDSolve[{pde, ic}, {S, T}, {t, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10}, {r, 0, 10}];
ContourPlot[Evaluate[T[t, z, 1] /. sol], {z, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Do I need more equations and initial conditions? By the way, the pdes  can not be solved when sequence of equation is different. Is it bug of mma? For example, pdes below can not be solved.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"] ;
n = 100;
pde = {D[T[t, z], t] == n^-1 S[t, z], D[S[t, z], z] == -S[t, z]};
ic = {T[0, z] == 1, S[t, 0] == 1};
sol = NDSolve[{pde, ic}, {S, T}, {t, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10}];
ContourPlot[Evaluate[T[t, z] /. sol], {z, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

while pdes below can be solved.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"] ;
n = 100;
pde = {D[S[t, z], z] == -S[t, z], D[T[t, z], t] == n^-1 S[t, z]};
ic = {T[0, z] == 1, S[t, 0] == 1};
sol = NDSolve[{pde, ic}, {S, T}, {t, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10}];
ContourPlot[Evaluate[T[t, z] /. sol], {z, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

---

In fact, my real pdes is a little more complicated than 1st pde.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"] ;
n = 100;B=10;p=10^-8;T0=10^-5;S0=10^-6;
pde = {D[S[t, z, r], z] == -2Im[k]*S[t, z, r], 
D[T[t, z, r], t] == n^-1 S[t, z, r]}/.k->(1 - (n*T[t, z, r]^(3/2))/(T[t, z, r]^(3/2) - B*T[t, z, r]^(3/2) + I*p*n))^(1/2);
ic = {T[0, z, r] == T0, S[t, 0, r] == S0*Exp[-r^2]};
sol = NDSolve[{pde, ic}, {S, T}, {t, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10}, {r, 0, 10}];
ContourPlot[Evaluate[T[t, z, 1] /. sol], {z, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Comment: It is strange that `NDSolve` stumbles on a simple system of equations.

Comment: I just asked experts in PDE. They said that it is better to write code by myself to solve pdes, not using mma or library in matlab. In this way, I know exactly what is happening.

Comment: How about my first question to solve T[t,z,r] and S[t,z,r]? Thank you.

Comment: `NDSolve[{pde, ic}, {S, T}, {t, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10}, 
 DependentVariables -> {T[t, z], S[t, z]}]`

Comment: With the new added equation, the first system is over-determined.

Comment: OK. I have deleted the new added equation.

Comment: @user21 `DependentVariables` doesn't seem to help here.

Comment: You need to add @xzczd in the comment or I won't get the reminder. _v11.3_ produces results in 1st and 2nd case, but they're not correct. Generally equations like ` D[S[t, z], z] == -S[t, z]` is troublesome, because it doesn't involve derivative of `t`, see e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/163923/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133731/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/184281/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/183745/1871 I'm not quite sure what happens in your case (`"FiniteElement"` is chosen here), but the underlying issue is similar, I guess.

Comment: @xzczd, Physically, `S[t,z,r]` is laser intensity and `D[S[t, z, r], z] == -S[t, z, r]` expresses laser absorption. Thus, there is no derivative of `t`.

Comment: I didn't mean there's anything wrong with your system. I just mean currently `NDSolve` is having trouble with them. What's the purpose or your question? Understanding why `NDSolve` fails, solving the system with `NDSolve`, solving the system numerically, or solving the system?

Comment: @xzczd, my purpose is to solve `T[t,z,r]` and `S[t,z,r]` numerically in the first pdes.

Answer (score 3):

Since your target is just to solve 1st PDE system numerically, let me show you a finite difference method (FDM) based solution that should be applicable for your earlier problems ([1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/207463/1871), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/207471/1871)), as long as they're correct and well-posed.

First we solve your toy example analytically for comparision:

```
n = 100;
pde = {D[S[t, z, r], z] == -S[t, z, r], D[T[t, z, r], t] == n^-1 S[t, z, r]};
ic = {T[0, z, r] == 1, S[t, 0, r] == Exp[-r^2]};

rule = HoldPattern@LaplaceTransform[a_, __] :> a;
{teq, tic} = LaplaceTransform[{pde, ic[[2]]}, t, s] /. Rule @@ ic[[1]] /. rule;
{asolS[t_, z_, r_], asolT[t_, z_, r_]} = 
 InverseLaplaceTransform[DSolve[{teq, tic}, {S[t, z, r], T[t, z, r]}, {z}][[1, All, -1]],
   s, t]
(* {E^(-r^2 - z), 1/100 E^(-r^2 - z) (100 E^(r^2 + z) + t)} *)
{pde, ic} /. {S -> asolS, T -> asolT}
(* {{True, True}, {True, True}} *)
```

Then we solve the problem based on FDM. I'll use [pdetoae](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the generation of finite difference equation:

```
points = 25; domain = {0, 10}; grid = Array[# &, points, domain]; difforder = 2;
(* Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoafunc = pdetoae[{S, T}[t, z, r], {grid, grid, grid}, difforder];
del = Rest;
ae = {del /@ ptoafunc@pde[[1]], del@ptoafunc@pde[[2]]};
aeic = ptoafunc@ic;
var = Outer[#[#2, #3, #4] &, {S, T}, grid, grid, grid, 1] // Flatten;

{barray, marray} = CoefficientArrays[{ae, aeic} // Flatten, var]

sollst = LinearSolve[marray, -N@barray];

{solS, solT} = 
 ListInterpolation[#, {grid, grid, grid}] & /@ 
  ArrayReshape[sollst, {2, points, points, points}]

Manipulate[Plot[{#[t, z, r], #2[t, z, r]}, {z, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {Red, Dashed}}] & @@@ {{asolS, solS}, {asolT, solT}}, {t, 0,
   1}, {r, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An **extended comment** (might be a special analytical solution):

Your pde in S `D[S[t, z, r], z] == -S[t, z, r]` together with condition `S[t, 0, r] == Exp[-r^2]` has the general solution `S[t,z,r]=Exp[-z] Exp[-r^2]`

```
{D[S[t, z, r], z] == -S[t, z, r], S[t, 0, r] == Exp[-r^2]} /. S -> Function[{t, z, r}, Exp[-z] Exp[-r^2] ] // Simplify
(*{True,True}*)
```

That means `S` is independent of `t`!

The remaining equations give `T[t,z,r]==1+t 1/n Exp[-z] Exp[-r^2]`

```
{D[T[t, z, r], t] == n^-1 Exp[-z] Exp[-r^2], T[0, z, r] == 1} /. T -> Function[{t, z, r}, 1 + t/n Exp[-z] Exp[-r^2]] // Simplify
(*{True,True}*)
```

Don't know why Mathematica couldn't find this solution.

**addendum(might be the answer)**

You can solve the problem numerically in two steps:

```
solS = NDSolveValue[{D[S[t, z, r], z] == -S[t, z, r],S[t, 0, r] == Exp[-r^2]}, S, {t, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10}, {r, 0, 10} ,Method -> "FiniteElement" ]
solT = NDSolveValue[{D[T[t, z, r], t] == 1/n solS[t, z, r], T[0, z, r] == 1}, T, {t, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10}, {r, 0, 10} ] 
ContourPlot[solT[t, z, 1], {z, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 10},PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Since the system is linear, this should be the only analytic solution. I've found it with `LaplaceTransform` and `DSolve`, see my answer for more detail.

Comment: @xzczd, I will read your great code carefully, thanks a lot. Never thought that I should write so many codes in mma.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann, I will also try your way. In fact, I simplied my pdes. The real equation is `D[S[t, z, r], 
  z] == - 2 Im[(1 - (n*T[t, z, r]^(3/2))/(
     T[t, z, r]^(3/2) - B*T[t, z, r]^(3/2) + I*p*n))^(1/2)]*
  S[t, z, r]` and `D[T[t, z, r], t] == -n^-1*D[S[t, z, r], z]`. I wonder how to solve it in your way.

Comment: @sixpenny  This system is completely different to that you asked for!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, Sorry. At the beginning, I wanted to simply the pdes only to know the skills to solve it. Did not know that they are so different. The real pdes is updated in the original post. Anyway, I also enjoy your skill for the simplified pdes. Thanks.